# ContentType - Dynamic Data Structure Storage C# + SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an assignment - I need to store dynamic content in database in form of content types.

`ContentTypes` are basically a key-value collection. I need to store this data in database and make sure the content types are queryable and can be indexed. I can't create a table for each content type because they can be changed at runtime and that would mean dropping of table and losing data.

Does anyone know any good approach for this? I need to mention that DB will in the end contain ~1 million content types. In the end this data would be accessed by .NET application.

Comment: what can each content type contains as info?

Comment: Strings and integers

Answer (score 0):

if values should be queryable then you can work as following sample

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContentTypeDetail] 
(
    [ContentTypeDetailId] uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
    [ContentTypeId] uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,  
    [ColumnType] smallint  NOT NULL,  
    [ColumnValueString] nvarchar(1000)  NULL,
    [ColumnValueInt] int  NULL  
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContentTypeDetail] ADD CONSTRAINT [ContentTypeDetail_PK]      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ContentTypeDetailId]
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContentType] 
(
    [ContentTypeId] uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(100)  NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContentType] ADD CONSTRAINT [ContentType_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ContentTypeId]
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContentTypeDetail] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [ContentType_ContentTypeDetail_FK1] FOREIGN KEY 
(
    [ContentTypeId]
)
REFERENCES [dbo].[ContentType] 
(
    [ContentTypeId]
)
GO
```

of course you have to add appropriate indexes